# Generating bounding box based on tile numbers using slippy map tiles method

Tags: coordinate-system, tile-map-service, extents, slippy

Description:
I am writing a map cache server for my company. I have to get input data based on tms standard and send a request to wms server to render and cache map files.
I am using [slippy map tiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Python) formula to convert x,y,z to latlon. (North West)
Also for finding the other corner (south East), I am converting x+1 and y+1 to degrees. We are using srs 4326

My problem:
It works basically, but the map files are a little scaled up! in lower zoom levels, the problem is very obvious.